# Can EM radiation penetrate through the walls of an aluminium box (Faraday cage)?

Tags: electromagnetism

What's the best possible frequency to use and is it high frequency or low frequency that has the highest ability to penetrate an aluminium wall?

Comment: Insufficient information. How thick is the aluminium, what fraction do you want to penetrate?

Comment: High energy gammas will penetrate quite easily.

Comment: @JonCuster: That should be an answer.